# Can I install a hard disk with higher capacity than that specified in my laptops specification document

Tags: hard-drive, laptop

Please, I have a HP Compaq 6530b Laptop with 250gb hard drive, and I want to buy a second hard drive and use a caddy to install it as a second hard drive.
The max amount specified in my laptops specification document is 250gb but I want to know if I can install a 320gb and above without it spoiling.
The reason I'm asking is there was a time I bought a 500gb Seagate and installed it on the main slot but it didn't last three months and it suddenly became too slow to do anything, even using an external connector to connect it to a system takes it about an hour to show up, so I don't know if it was the laptop that spoilt the disk because the disk was too big for it or it was a fake.
[Here is a screenshot of the storage specification for my laptop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dSdeA.png)

Comment: Your assumptions are all wrong.  A hard drive can be bad whether a seagate hard drive or some other model hard drive that you(probably wrongly again), think might have been falsely advertised as seagate. I know one guy that won't buy seagate because of bad experiences with them.   There is no such thing as a fake hard drive. Furthermore, a hard drive can go bad e.g. one reason is power supplied to it can be problematic. Various reasons. Not because of a size difference!!

Comment: @barlop thanks, after that experience, I bought a Fujitsu 250gb because I was afraid of Seagate

Answer (score 0):

The specs for your laptop are not the max, but what is preinstalled. There are boundaries, but those are into the terabytes. You should be fine upgrading to a 500GB drive.

IF the drive is an SSD, keep in mind that SSD's will slow down if 25% or less space is free, depending on the brand. With too few space left, the disk cannot perform TRIM anymore and the disk becomes fragmented, which slows the disk down. Restoring the disk back to full speed requires lots of effort.

Comment: thanks, this cleared it up for me